# How to apply $lookup with conditions in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework, lookup

I am using `mongodb` databases and want to apply `$lookup` on 2 `collections` but with specific conditions. 
I have one `collection` named `Company` like this

```
new Schema({
    name: String,
    benefit: String,
    benefitDesc: String,
    company_url: String,
    logoUrl: String,
    coverUrl: String,
    desc: String,
    createdAt: String,
    categoryId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'categories' },
})
```

And another `collection` named `Referrallinks` like this

```
new Schema({
    referral_link: String,
    referral_code: String,
    isLink: Number,
    offer_name: String,
    offer_desc: String,
    user_email: String,
    companyId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'companies' },
    addedByAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    number_of_clicks: Number,
    referral_country: String,
    link_status: String,
    categoryId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'categories' },
    number_of_clicks: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    createdAt: String,
    updatedAt: String,
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' }
})
```

Now when i apply this `$lookup`

```
Company.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'referrallinks',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'companyId',
        as: 'referrals'
    }
}])
```

So i am getting all companies with `referrals` as `array` like this

```
[
  {name : '', benefit : '', benefiDesc : '', referrals : []},
  {name : '', benefit : '', benefiDesc : '', referrals : []},
  {name : '', benefit : '', benefiDesc : '', referrals : []},
  .....
]
```

But i want to have only referrals in each `company's` `referrals` array that have `link_status` value `Approved`.

**Note : ** I also want to have `category` object with `company` and tried this aggregation but it gives error

```
{
  from: "referrallinks",
  let: { company_id: "$_id" },
  pipeline: [{
    $match: {
      $expr: {
       $and: [
        { $eq: [ "$$company_id", "$companyId" ] },
        { $eq: [ "$link_status", "Approved" ] }
       ]
     }
    },
  {
    $lookup : {
    from : "categories",
    let  : {"category_id" : "$categoryId"},
    pipeline : [
      {
        $match : {
          $expr : {
            $eq : ["category_id","$_id"]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    as : "company"
   }
  }
 }],
 as: "referrals"
}
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$lookup with custom pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) to specify additional filtering condition:

```
Company.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "referrallinks",
        let: { company_id: "$_id" },
        pipeline: [{
            $match: {
                $expr: {
                    $and: [
                        { $eq: [ "$$company_id", "$companyId" ] },
                        { $eq: [ "$link_status", "Approved" ] }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }],
        as: "referrals"
    }
}])
```

EDIT: to run nested `$lookup` your code should look like below:

```
Company.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "referrallinks",
        let: { company_id: "$_id" },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $and: [
                            { $eq: [ "$$company_id", "$companyId" ] },
                            { $eq: [ "$link_status", "Approved" ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "categories",
                    localField: "categoryId",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "company"
                }
            }
        ],
        as: "referrals"
    }
}])
```

Comment: There is some error in your query. See error here 

https://imgur.com/6tRCUuv

Comment: @ahsan ah yes, `$expr` was missing, please try again

Comment: Can i have `populate` with `$lookup`? like i have `companyId` as (ObjectId) of `category` collection and i want to have `category` also in my results.

Comment: @ahsan afair you have to keep using `$lookup` in such case

Comment: i tried but not got a luck. Can you modify your answer?

Comment: @ahsan you can take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59866703/lookup-for-aggregation-for-two-layer-relationship/59867103#59867103

Comment: yes i saw and i tried also but didn't get a luck. See my updated question. I included what i have tried so far

Comment: @ahsan you should run second `$lookup` inside of `pipeline` just like in the example I've sent you

Comment: my second lookup is inside of pipeline. Just copy this pipeline to any code editor and you will see that my second `$lookup` is inside of `piepline`. Update your answer if you can

Comment: `$eq : ["category_id","$_id"]` is incorrect. That should be ` $eq : ["$$category_id","$_id"]` since you want to refer a variable

Comment: Also tried this but it's still giving an error like this `Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" found.`

Comment: @ahsan u have one redundant curly brace, change `}],` to `],`

Comment: You have a syntax error, this bracket needs to be moved before you start $lookup since $match needs to be closed so it requires one more

Comment: I dind't understand. Can you modify your answer?

Comment: @ahsan sure, try now

Comment: i tried and it worked. But there's issue. now `company` is nesting in `referral` object. but i want it outside of `referral` object

Comment: @ahsan can you open another question to keep this question-answer clear and readable for other SO users ?

Comment: Yes i asked that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59904888/how-can-i-get-the-referenced-dcoument-as-nested-document-with-lookup-in-mongodb