# How can i get the referenced dcoument as nested document with $lookup in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, lookup

I am using `mongodb` databases and want to apply `$lookup` on 2 `collections` but with specific conditions. I have one collection named `Company` like this

```
new Schema({
name: String,
benefit: String,
benefitDesc: String,
company_url: String,
logoUrl: String,
coverUrl: String,
desc: String,
createdAt: String,
categoryId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'categories' },
})
```

And another collection named Referrallinks like this

```
new Schema({
referral_link: String,
referral_code: String,
isLink: Number,
offer_name: String,
offer_desc: String,
user_email: String,
companyId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'companies' },
addedByAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: true },
number_of_clicks: Number,
referral_country: String,
link_status: String,
categoryId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'categories' },
number_of_clicks: { type: Number, default: 0 },
createdAt: String,
 updatedAt: String,
 userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' }
})
```

Now when i apply this `$lookup` query

```
Company.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "referrallinks",
        let: { company_id: "$_id" },
        pipeline: [{
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $and: [
                            { $eq: ["$$company_id", "$companyId"] },
                            { $eq: ["$link_status", "Approved"] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "categories",
                    localField: "categoryId",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "category"
                }
            }
        ],
        as: "referrals"
    }
}])
```

So i am getting `category` object inside each company's `referral` object's `key`. But i want it outside of `referral` Object like this

```
[
 {name : '', benefit : '', benefiDesc : '', referrals : [], category : {}},
 {name : '', benefit : '', benefiDesc : '', referrals : [], category : {}},
 {name : '', benefit : '', benefiDesc : '', referrals : [], category : {}},
 .....
]
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to move your nested `$lookup` out of first one and run as a separate pipeline step:

```
Company.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "referrallinks",
            let: { company_id: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [{
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $and: [
                            { $eq: [ "$$company_id", "$companyId" ] },
                            { $eq: [ "$link_status", "Approved" ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }],
            as: "referrals"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "categories",
            localField: "referrals.categoryId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "categories"
        }
    }
])
```

Note that `referrals.categoryId` evaluates to an array of `ObjectId` values

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pQMlE7rdEtU)